# hadoop namenode doesn't start with "sbin/start-dfs.sh" but does with "bin/hadoop namenode" (despite no errors showing)

Tags: linux, hadoop, hadoop2

If I run:

```
sbin/start-dfs.sh
```

Then it doesn't actually start a namenode despite printing:

```
Starting namenodes on [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: starting namenode, logging to /home/myuser/apps/hadoop-2.7.4/logs/hadoop-myuser-namenode-mybox.out
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /home/myuser/apps/hadoop-2.7.4/logs/hadoop-myuser-datanode-mybox.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /home/myuser/apps/hadoop-2.7.4/logs/hadoop-myuser-secondarynamenode-mybox.out
```

*BUT* if I instead do `bin/hadoop namenode` then the namenode DOES start. Why?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have hadoop-2.* in your machiene,

For **sbin/start-dfs.sh**

Your output seems ok,
check jps or try to login into namenode url,

and for **bin/hadoop namenode:**

open your $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop file with gedit or any editor,
verify what its going to do for argument **namenode**

Usually for formatting your namenode,  command **hadoop or hdfs**  namenode -format is used.

For starting dfs and yarn

**start-dfs.sh**

**start-yarn.sh**

command will be used

Comment: None of that worked. In the end, I had to change a lot of settings in the XML files as well as permissions on some folders for the hadoop user.

Comment: How you are running, have you set class path for everything or you are navigating to that folder. {For test do not create separate user for hadoop and try to install hadoop }

Comment: may i know your environment configuration